# How to filter content "by year, by author, by paper type" in Publication kind of page?

Tags: views

I am beginner in Drupal.

I am creating page named as "Publication Papers".

On this page, content is coming from different database other than main one.

So I created different template for this page and then fetched data directly from specific database.

But now in that page I would like to add filters such as,

"By Author
By Year/Month
By Type of paper"

These are actual fields in that database.

So publication is just a basic page of drupal in which content is coming directly from specific database.

Ask me if you need more information regarding this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: pls elaborate how are you using views module and if possible send a screenshot of views you have created

Comment: Hello Harshal,I haven't used any views yet. I am asking that is it possible to add views to the data coming outside of drupal database? Like content is not coming from drupal database. It's being fetched from different database using specific template. And I want to filter those data.

Comment: pls mention your drupal version d7 or d6?

Comment: drupal 7 or drupal 6?

Comment: also refer the following for exensive detail on how o enable views for external database : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/how-do-i-display-an-external-database-data

Comment: It is Drupal 7...